# Correct constant for Khintchine-Kahane inequality?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading this paper http://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/kloft12a/kloft12a.pdf

In Lemma 1, it says the constant for the Khintchine-Kahane inequality is q*. But if so, I don't think the authors can get the result in Proposition 2. I doubt that the correct constant is q*, instead, I think it should be q.

The source that the authors get the constant is Lemma 3.3.1 and Proposition 3.4.1 in Kwapien and Woyczynski(1992), which is a book. But I don't have access to this book...

Can anybody help me to check if the author used the right constant? Thanks a lot!